# how to make `git add` work with `xargs`

Tags: git

xargs works with dos2unix but it doesn't work with git add.
    Why?

```
$ git status -s -uno | sed -n 's/^...//p' | xargs dos2unix -u
dos2unix: converting file Server.C to UNIX format ...
dos2unix: converting file Proxy.C to UNIX format ...
dos2unix: converting file Proxy.H to UNIX format ...

$ git status -s -uno
 M Server.C
 M Proxy.C
 M Proxy.H

$ git status -s -uno | sed -n 's/^...//p'
Server.C
Proxy.C
Proxy.H

$ git status -s -uno | sed -n 's/^...//p' | xargs git add
xargs: git: No such file or directory
```

What should I do so that the `xargs` works with `git add`?

Answer (score 5):

The line `git status -s -uno | sed -n 's/^...//p' | xargs git add` is correct, and works when I tested it.

The relevant error message is actually `git: No such file or directory`. I.e. the `git` command is not found, so try debugging it with something like `... | xargs echo $PATH` to see what `$PATH` is in the `xargs` process.

Also, as you've written it, it gives the same `git` invocation as

```
git add `git status -s -uno | sed -n 's/^...//p'`
```

i.e. `git add Server.C Proxy.C Proxy.H` in your example
(try with `... | xargs echo` instead of `... | xargs git add`)

If, for some reason (How many filenames can you give `git` as arguments?), you want separate `git add` calls
you need to use

```
... | xargs -L1 git add
```

to make `xargs` use each line as the argument to a separate `git add`

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont have the correct file paths to git add. Substitute an echo for git add to see what is passed in as well as what path you should be using. Maybe specify -u to git add and not pass in all the files and all the changed tracked files will be added to the index.

Answer (score 0):

example of adding freshly removed .d (dependency) files into GIT:

`git status |grep "\.d$" |awk {"print \$2"}| xargs git add`